# Simple 2D Convex Hull error with scipy.spatial

Tags: python

These very simple lines of code successfully take 2-dimensional coordinates and plot them accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull


rawdata = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=';')
data = rawdata[1:]



hull2d=ConvexHull(data)
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]


plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x, y, 'k-')
plt.show()
```

What it seems to do wrong is calculating the convex hull, which appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ8eE.png)

Shouldn't it create a hull around the the most outer points (Graham Scan)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not plotting the correct data. According to [Scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/spatial.html#convex-hulls) it should look like :

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rawdata = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=';')
points = rawdata[1:]
hull = ConvexHull(points)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex,0], points[simplex,1], 'k-')
plt.show()
```